# Procedimientos Alamcenados en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Me a surgido un problema usando Procedimientos Almacenados con Laravel y Mysql:

Mi código en Laravel es así:

```
$nombre = $request->nombre;
$presupuesto = $request->presupuesto;
$msg = ""; 
$res = DB::select("CALL insertDepartamento(?,?, @msg)", [$nombre, $presupuesto]);
foreach ($res as $data) {
    $msg = $data->msg;
}
return redirect("departamentos")->with('status', $msg );
```

Y mi procedimiento almacenado es:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertDepartamento`(in _nombre varchar(30), in _presupuesto double, out msg varchar(30))
BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
 SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
 ROLLBACK;
 END; 


 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
 BEGIN
 SHOW WARNINGS LIMIT 1;
 ROLLBACK;
 END;

 START TRANSACTION;
     if exists (select * from DEPARTAMENTO where nombre = _nombre) then
            set msg ="Ya existe el departamento";
            SELECT msg;
    else
            insert into DEPARTAMENTO values (null, _nombre, _presupuesto);
            set msg = "Departamento añadido con exito";
        SELECT msg;
    end if;
END
```

No tengo ningún problema al ejecutar el procedimiento desde Workbench y al hacerlo desde Laravel tampoco marca error, me devuelve el mensaje correctamente y todo parece ir bien, pero no se guardan los datos.
El auto incremento si avanza, pero no aparece ninguna fila que sea insertada desde Laravel.
¿Alguna idea de qué puede ser?
Estoy usando Xampp cómo servidor local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta parte del código estas iniciando la transacción pero necesitas confirmar la transacción y hacer que los cambios sean permanentes usando **COMMIT**:

```
...
...
START TRANSACTION;
     if exists (select * from DEPARTAMENTO where nombre = _nombre) then
            set msg ="Ya existe el departamento";
            SELECT msg;
    else
            insert into DEPARTAMENTO values (null, _nombre, _presupuesto);
            set msg = "Departamento añadido con exito";
        SELECT msg;
    end if;
COMMIT;
```

También puedes habilitar el modo "auto commit" usando:

```
SET autocommit = 1;
```

O

```
SET autocommit = ON;
```